# Add multilanguage to angular with i18n (aot)

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

I want to add support for multi language to my Angular2 project.
I followed the Angular document about internationalization here: 
[coockbook internationalization (I18N)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html)
I'm using angular-cli so I followed aot instructions.
If I serve it with this command from the terminal it works:

```
ng serve --aot --locale it --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/locale/messages.i
t.xlf
```

Now I want to give users the possibility to change language at runtime (I have all the translated messages in *locale* folder with xlf extension). Is that possible?

Comment: No, not without reloading a different index.html page, using the other locale.

Comment: How we can do  redirect on angular and web server? Can you provide some infimation plz?